# How to add new rows to dataframe for missing timestamps

Tags: r, dataframe, date, datetime, time

I have a dataframe of multiple classes with timestamps. In some cases, the timestamps are missing, so I would like to add a new row with the correct timestamp and times (each interval is about, *but not exactly*, 6 minutes). However, the new row should be the last Time + 6 minutes. Ideally I would also like to track per class how many stamps have been added as a percentage of the total stamps. Below is an example of my incorrect df:

```
   Class Time                 Timestamp
   <chr> <dttm>               <dbl>    
 1  1    2021-03-12 14:42:45  1
 2  1    2021-03-12 14:48:12  2
 3  1    2021-03-12 15:06:16  5
 4  1    2021-03-12 15:12:35  6
```

For which the corrected df would then be:

```
   Class Time                 Timestamp
   <chr> <dttm>               <dbl>    
 1  1    2021-03-12 14:42:45  1
 2  1    2021-03-12 14:48:12  2
 3  1    2021-03-12 14:54:12  3
 4  1    2021-03-12 15:00:12  4
 5  1    2021-03-12 15:06:16  5
 6  1    2021-03-12 15:12:35  6
```

Another difficulty lies in that some classes have multiple ranges of timestamps, so an example of an incorrect df would then be:

```
   Class Time                 Timestamp
   <chr> <dttm>               <dbl>    
 1  1    2021-03-12 14:42:45  1
 2  1    2021-03-12 14:48:12  2
 3  1    2021-03-12 14:54:12  3
 4  1    2021-03-12 15:06:16  5
 5  1    2021-04-19 12:06:12  1
 6  1    2021-04-19 12:12:56  2
 7  1    2021-04-19 12:18:32  3
 8  1    2021-04-19 12:30:21  5
 9  1    2021-04-19 12:36:08  6
```

Can you help me fix my missing timestamps issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  complete(Class, Timestamp = full_seq(Timestamp, 1)) %>%
  mutate(across(Time, ~ accumulate(.x, ~ if_else(!is.na(..2), ..2, ..1 + minutes(6)))))

# A tibble: 6 × 3
  Class Timestamp Time               
  <dbl>     <dbl> <dttm>             
1     1         1 2021-03-12 14:42:45
2     1         2 2021-03-12 14:48:12
3     1         3 2021-03-12 14:54:12
4     1         4 2021-03-12 15:00:12
5     1         5 2021-03-12 15:06:16
6     1         6 2021-03-12 15:12:35
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example using your sample data with multiple ranges per group. I assume that `Timestamp = 1` will be present to start each run of ranges.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  mutate(
    class_grp = cumsum(Timestamp == 1), .by = Class 
  ) |>
  complete(
    Class, class_grp, Timestamp = 1:6
  ) |>
  mutate(
    is_added = is.na(Time),
    consecutive_added_id = consecutive_id(is_added) * is_added
  ) |>
  fill(Time) |>
  mutate(
    Time = Time + minutes(6) * row_number() * is_added,
    .by = c(Class, class_grp, consecutive_added_id)
  )
# # A tibble: 12 × 6
#    Class class_grp Timestamp Time                is_added consecutive_added_id
#    <int>     <int>     <int> <dttm>              <lgl>                <int>
#  1     1         1         1 2021-03-12 14:42:45 FALSE                    0
#  2     1         1         2 2021-03-12 14:48:12 FALSE                    0
#  3     1         1         3 2021-03-12 14:54:12 FALSE                    0
#  4     1         1         4 2021-03-12 15:00:12 TRUE                     2
#  5     1         1         5 2021-03-12 15:06:16 FALSE                    0
#  6     1         1         6 2021-03-12 15:12:16 TRUE                     4
#  7     1         2         1 2021-04-19 12:06:12 FALSE                    0
#  8     1         2         2 2021-04-19 12:12:56 FALSE                    0
#  9     1         2         3 2021-04-19 12:18:32 FALSE                    0
# 10     1         2         4 2021-04-19 12:24:32 TRUE                     6
# 11     1         2         5 2021-04-19 12:30:21 FALSE                    0
# 12     1         2         6 2021-04-19 12:36:08 FALSE                    0
```

You can use the `is_added` column to track the percent added by class, `result |> summarize(pct_added = mean(is_added) * 100, .by = Class)`.

---

Using this sample data:

```
df = read.table(text = ' Class Time                 Timestamp
 1  1    "2021-03-12 14:42:45"  1
 2  1    "2021-03-12 14:48:12"  2
 3  1    "2021-03-12 14:54:12"  3
 4  1    "2021-03-12 15:06:16"  5
 5  1    "2021-04-19 12:06:12"  1
 6  1    "2021-04-19 12:12:56"  2
 7  1    "2021-04-19 12:18:32"  3
 8  1    "2021-04-19 12:30:21"  5
 9  1    "2021-04-19 12:36:08"  6', header = T) |>
  mutate(Time = ymd_hms(Time))
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code generates this error "Error: object 'Time' not found"

Comment: Does it give that error if you run it on the copy/pasteable sample data at the bottom of my question? Does your real data have a column named `Time`?

Comment: If you're having trouble on your real data, please provide a copy/pasteable sample using `dput`, like `dput(your_data[1:20, ])` for the first 20 rows.

Comment: Yes it gives the error on your copy/pasteable sample data as well.

Comment: What versions of R, `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and `lubridate` are you running? The code works for me using R 4.2.2, dplyr 1.1.2, tidyr 1.3.0, and lubridate 1.9.0. You would certainly need R > 4.1 for the `|>` and `dplyr > 1.1.0` for the `.by`, but those could be worked around if you are using older versions.

Comment: I have the same `dplyr` and `tidyr`, but `lubridate` 1.9.2 and `R` 4.3.0, but I am denied access when downgrading `lubridate` to 1.9.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254075/discussion-between-trm-and-gregor-thomas).